# How can I read a server log file?

Tags: http, logging

I set up an httpd server in linux mandriva 2010. How can I find the server log file? Do I have to write that log file?

I'm a new bee in this area. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a Redhat user so the locations might be slightly off but this should give you something to go on:

Most likely it's in /var/log/httpd/access_log and errors should be in /var/log/httpd/error_log

If not there possibly /var/log/apache2/access_log and /var/log/apache2/error_log

If you still can't find it then you need to look for the apache conf file. Usually this is /etc/httpd/httpd.conf

Look for the line CustomLog or ErrorLog in that file and it will tell you where the logs are saved.